# Principles of creating a consistent (point-in-time) backup

Tags: backup

As far as my experience goes, **in order to create a useful, and consistent backup, one must involve the application handling the data to be backed up**. I'd like to validate my findings with fellow sysadmins.

Consider the situation that an application has a file opened for R/W, and while held open, a separate backup process reads the file. (And is allowed to do so – if we'd use flocks, and *mandatory* ones instead of *advisory* at that, we'd have to involve the application anyway). It should be commonly agreed upon that the backup created of this open file might be inconsistent.

Using snapshots on the filesystem level cannot completely alleviate this; as we can't guarantee that at snapshot point in time *t* all applications have written consistent files to the disk (assume that at *t* we are able to have flushed all buffers).

So, when creating a proper backup plan, one must always keep in mind on which applications write data, and how they're doing it – and make sure that they write consistent files to disk before taking a snapshot/backup.

Do you agree with me, or have I made fundamental mistakes when pondering this?

*(Please do not answer this question with any specific HOWTO's, as this is about general, "high-level" principles. Also, just to make sure, this is **not** about DB's, as the problem has been solved there already).*

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: I wrote a [very long article](http://www.halfgaar.net/backing-up-unix) agreeing with you :)

Comment: Long, but an interesting read!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a good understanding of the issues.

The standard snapshot approach I have seen is to shutdown the services that would be writing to the file system, break the snapshot and restart the services.  Backup the side not being written.

Another approach is to be able to export a point in time set of data from the application.  Then backup the exported data.  This is one approach that databases may use.  Data may be transformed during the export, so there may be additional steps to importing the data.

An alternative approach I have used with databases, is to mark files as being backed up while they are copied.  This may defer updates while the backup is running, or may allow replay of the changes at a later time.  This requires change logs which also need to be backed up.

I generally exclude database files from my standard backups, and use one of the alternate approaches to get point in time data from the database.

Plan carefully before recovering a database.  I've rarely needed to recover a full database to a point in time.  Cold backups (database shutdown) may be appropriate for a database used in training.  I've regretted providing similar rollback for testing databases.

Comment: Interesting bit about shutdown/snapshot/restart and dumping, a.k.a. exporting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you agree with me, or have I made fundamental mistakes when
>   pondering this?

Fundamentally, I'd like to point out an important consideration: the fact that power outages still happen greatly helps with backups. Any application that handles a power outage (i.e. hard loss of CPU and RAM including disk cache) can also handle a restore from snapshot. Any application that doesn't  - yes you are correct in this situations - requires special care.

This is a solved problem for many classes of data stores - in particular for  the data store which is described as "journaled" or for any non-volatile non-toy database engine.

Things can get complicated when one app uses multiple filesystems, but some snapshot methods can keep them consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking on the same thing. Maybe using CQRS and event sourcing or any other append only strategy is a good solution. If you save attachment in the filesystem instead of the event storage, then you should flag the files for delete and delete them only after a backup. So if delete happens during the backup, it won't have any effect on the backup consistency. As of the query databases, I think it is better to rebuild them on a separate server using the backup of the event storage, so it won't affect the read performance of your running application and you can be sure that it is point in time consistent too. I am still not sure if it is possible to do a consistent backup on a normal application without stopping it.